# Is there a way to have subheader on a TableView in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to adapt a TableView that has TableViewColumns in a way that it has header and subheaders.

For example:

table with subheaders

[image]

As far as i know i can only do it like this:

the table i have now

[image]

In code i frequently do:

```
                TableViewColumn {
                    id: zoneNumber
                    title: qsTr("teste")
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    width: col_zone_width
                    movable: false
                    resizable: false
                    delegate:
                        Rectangle {
                            border.width: 1
                            border.color: globals.table.borderColor
                            color: globals.table.color
                            height: parent.height
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            Text {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                                color: globals.text.textColor
                                text: (styleData.row + 1)
                                font.bold: globals.menu.fontBold
                                font.pointSize: globals.text.textSize
                                font.family: robotoRegular.name
                            }
                        }
                }
```

Reading the documentation title in TableViewColumn only accepts a string.

Then on TableView i have,

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle{
    id:recHeader
    width:styleData.width+20
    height:301
    Text {
        anchors.fill:parent
        text:styleData.value
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

That way it seems impossible to do what i'm trying to achieve.

Is there a solution for this? maybe parsing `styleData.value` to return a different component?

note: i'm using TableViewColumn from QtQuick.Controls 1.4, TableView from QtQuick 2.2

Comment: A note about your note: you can't mix the new TableView in Qt Quick with the old TableView API in Qt Quick Controls 1. It's probably using the type from whichever import came last in your file (likely `import QtQuick.Controls 1.x`, otherwise it probably wouldn't work).

Comment: I see, from some exemple i found now on a search, this version of TableView probably is not meant to be used with this version of TableViewColumn.